# General interaction with more than 2 classes

Tags: c#, c++, qt

So still a lot to learn...

I have 3 independent classes, named `Beverage`, `Stock` & `Balance`.

These classes are interconnected in that way that you can only order a beverage if you have enough balance and there's still supply.

With 2 classes it's easier to write it out, but with 3 classes I don't know how these classes have to interact...
Anyone any ideas?

Comment: there's a lot of unknowns, too many to give a quality answer

Comment: So this question is a little vague.  Try to take a small example of what you are having trouble with and post it.  There are millions of ways for classes to interact.

Comment: Is this a C# or C++ question? and how does qt play into this.  Do you want solutions in C++ or C#?

Comment: You've started well; you've identified *nouns*, and nouns tend to correspond to classes. Now there are two questions to answer before you design your classes. First, of those nouns, which does it make sense to have more than one instance?  You can clearly have two beverages. Can you have two balances? Two stocks?  Objects that you can logically only have one of can be tricky to model, so identify those first. Second, what are the verbs that apply to the nouns, and particularly what are the verbs that relate the nouns?  A car *has* wheels but *drives on* a road; those are very different verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may be:

```
public interface IOrder
{
   bool CanOrder(); 
   bool Order(); 
}


public class Beverage : IOrder 
{
   Stock _stock = null; 
   Balance _balance = null; 

   //In order to be able to construct Beverage, you HAVE TO
   //pass Stock and Balance 
   public Beverage(Stock stock, Balance balance) {
      _stock = stock; 
      _balance = balance;
   } 

   //interface implementation
   public void Order () {

      if(!CanOrder())
        return;

      //make order
   }

   //interface implementation
   public bool CanOrder() {
       //check here against _stock and _balance 
       //if can order
   }
}
```

Comment: Now this is really a brave thing to do, to answer such a vague question. An upvote for that.

Comment: Thanks Tigran! As a noob it took me quite a while to figure it out; therefore the late reply, but your post was very useful!